# Looking for a free/very low cost, asp.net & SQL Server based forum software

Tags: sql-server, asp.net

I need to setup a users forum/discussion board (maybe 200 users max) for supporting a custom piece of software.

I prefer asp.net (vb) against SQL Server, customization ability would be nice, but I would like for it to be usable right out of the box with little effort on my part.

Recommendations/links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used a site called [OpenSourceCMS](http://aspx.opensourcecms.com/) to research this type of thing in the past.  Everything they list is open source and free, and it's all rated by the site visitors.  They also create trials for all of the packages so you try them out before installing them on your hardware.

Ed

Answer (score 1):

How low cost? [InstantForum](http://www.instantasp.co.uk/Products/InstantForum/) is 199 USD and is a pretty neat solution.

[Snitz](http://forum.snitz.com/) is free, as is [DMG Forums](http://www.dmgforums.com/).

The above are VB based solutions, but there's plenty more available if you can work with C#.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if they haev a VB build or not, but I've used [YAF (Yet Another Forum)](http://www.yetanotherforum.net/) fourm in the past and it has worked out very well. It's also open source and has a very active message board for questions.